# Order on a list

Tags: r

I've encountered an application where I need to sort a data.frame by column numbers, and none of the [usual solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/6871968#6871968) seem to allow that.

The context is creating an `as.data.frame.by` method.  Since a `by` object will have its last column as the value column and the first ncol-1 columns as the index columns.  `melt` returns it sorted backwards--index 3, then index 2, then index 1.  For compatibility with `latex.table.by` I'd like to sort it forwards.  But I'm having trouble doing that in a sufficiently generic way.  The commented-out line in the function below is my best attempt so far.

```
as.data.frame.by <- function( x, colnames=paste("IDX",seq(length(dim(x))),sep="" ), ... ) {
  num.by.vars <- length(dim(x))
    res <- melt(unclass(x))
  res <- na.omit(res)
    colnames(res)[seq(num.by.vars)] <- colnames
    #res <- res[ order(res[ , seq(num.by.vars)] ) , ] # Sort the results by the by vars in the heirarchy given
    res
}

dat <- transform( ChickWeight, Time=cut(Time,3), Chick=cut(as.numeric(Chick),3) )
my.by <- by( dat, with(dat,list(Time,Chick,Diet)), function(x) sum(x$weight) )
> as.data.frame(my.by)
            IDX1         IDX2 IDX3 value
1  (-0.021,6.99] (0.951,17.3]    1  3475
2      (6.99,14] (0.951,17.3]    1  5969
3        (14,21] (0.951,17.3]    1  8002
4  (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    1   640
5      (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    1  1596
6        (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    1  2900
13 (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    2  2253
14     (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    2  4734
15       (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    2  7727
22 (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    3   666
23     (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    3  1391
24       (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    3  2109
25 (-0.021,6.99]    (33.7,50]    3  1647
26     (6.99,14]    (33.7,50]    3  3853
27       (14,21]    (33.7,50]    3  7488
34 (-0.021,6.99]    (33.7,50]    4  2412
35     (6.99,14]    (33.7,50]    4  5448
36       (14,21]    (33.7,50]    4  8101
```

With the line uncommented, it returns gibberish (it just treats the whole data.frame as a vector, with disastrous results).

I've even tried clever stuff like `res <- res[ order( ...=list(res[,1],res[,2]) ) , ]` but to no avail.

I suspect there's a simple way to do this, but I'm not seeing it.

**Edit for clarification**: I want to not have to specify column names. Instead, I want to be able to sort it by a numerical vector (e.g. sort by columns 1:4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(my.by)
mydf[order(mydf$IDX3, mydf$IDX2, mydf$IDX1) , ]
            IDX1         IDX2 IDX3 value
1  (-0.021,6.99] (0.951,17.3]    1  3475
3        (14,21] (0.951,17.3]    1  8002
2      (6.99,14] (0.951,17.3]    1  5969
4  (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    1   640
6        (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    1  2900
5      (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    1  1596
13 (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    2  2253
15       (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    2  7727
14     (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    2  4734
22 (-0.021,6.99]  (17.3,33.7]    3   666
24       (14,21]  (17.3,33.7]    3  2109
23     (6.99,14]  (17.3,33.7]    3  1391
25 (-0.021,6.99]    (33.7,50]    3  1647
27       (14,21]    (33.7,50]    3  7488
26     (6.99,14]    (33.7,50]    3  3853
34 (-0.021,6.99]    (33.7,50]    4  2412
36       (14,21]    (33.7,50]    4  8101
35     (6.99,14]    (33.7,50]    4  5448
```

Or ;

```
my.by <- by( dat, with(dat,list(Diet,Chick, Time)), function(x) sum(x$weight) )
mydf <- as.data.frame(my.by)
```

EDIT: Or this produces same output as up top using numeric column indices:

```
 mydf <- as.data.frame(my.by)
 mydf[ do.call(order, mydf[, 3:1] ) , ]
```

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer: I want to not have to specify column names.  Instead, I want to be able to sort it by a numerical vector (e.g. sort by columns 1:4).

Comment: See above. The do.call method of passing dataframes to `order` is illustrated on `help(order)` page.

Comment: Nice.  Thanks.  I need to look more closely into `do.call`, as I suspect it would solve many of my problems :-)

Comment: Yes. It took me a couple of years to understand that `do.call` was the answer to many of my problems as well. `do.call` does for functions what `get` and `paste` do for data-objects, converting character representations into language objects, and allowing  multiple values to construct an evaluated expression.

Comment: So can I think of `do.call` as being useful whenever I need to pass something to `...`?

Comment: I would need to see a bit more context. Are you talking about catching `...` arguments insde a function? In that case you generally need to do something like `lisargs <- list(...)` and then work with 'lisargs'.

Comment: No, the other way around--passing a list to a function which catches comma-separated arguments into a list in the manner you described (see the first line of `order`).

Comment: I think the answer is yes. `order` doesn't deal well on its own with arguments supplied as a list. You get the uninformative error message asking if "you called sort on a list."

Comment: Thanks.  (He said, thereby ignoring the automated message to please move the discussion to chat) :-)